# How to wait for service HTTP call to finish in component

Tags: angular, typescript, service, components

I have a service in which i'm sending HTTP request to the web api and waiting for response. I'm calling this service function in ngOnInit().

I want component to wait for service call to finish and depending upon the HTTP response i should redirect user.

**Problem**
I call service function and component does not wait for it to finish and renders the page on screen then after 2 3 seconds it correctly redirects.. I don't want it to render..

**web service**

```
isTokenValid(token: any){

const body = token;
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post('http://'+this.web_url+':'+this.web_port+'/api/Authentication', body, {
  headers: headers
})
.map((data: Response) =>data.json());
}
```

**service exampe code**

```
verifyAccessToken(vaildDest: String, invalidDest: String, inverse:Boolean){
var localStorageObj = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');

if(localStorageObj == null){
  // no user details present in browser

  if(inverse) this.router.navigate([invalidDest]);
  return;

}

var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorageObj);
var token = currentUser.AccessToken;
var email = currentUser.Email;
var isAccessTokenValid = false;
console.log(token);
var jsonStr = {
  "AccessToken": token,
  "Email": email
}
this.webService.isTokenValid(jsonStr)
.subscribe(
  data => {
    isAccessTokenValid = data["AccessValidation"]; 
    console.log("TOKEN SERVICE => isValid: "+isAccessTokenValid);
    // success connection

    if(!isAccessTokenValid){
      // access token is not valid now we will send refresh token
      console.log("=> Access token is not valid sending refresh token... ");


      if(inverse) this.router.navigate([invalidDest]);

    }
    else{
      // access token is valid so we can continue operation
      if(!inverse) this.router.navigate([invalidDest]);

    }

  },error => {
    console.log("Error while validating token");

  },
  () => {
    // 'onCompleted' callback.
    // No errors, route to new page here

  }
);
 }
```

**Component code**

```
constructor(private router: Router, private tokenService:TokenService) { }


ngOnInit() {
  this.tokenService.verifyAccessToken("","/welcome", true);

  // i want to stop it here and dont render current component until above call is finished
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6674

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off using a `RouteGuard`, such as [`CanActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you to move the logic & the variables from service to component.

Service.ts :

```
function tryLogin(...put here your args): Observable<any> {
   return this.webService.isTokenValid(jsonStr);
   // Yep, just this. Usually services don't handle logic.
}
```

Component.ts :

```
this.tokenService.verifyAccessToken("","/welcome", true)
.subscribe(
  data => {
    isAccessTokenValid = data["AccessValidation"]; 
    console.log("TOKEN SERVICE => isValid: "+isAccessTokenValid);
    // success connection

    if(!isAccessTokenValid){
      // access token is not valid now we will send refresh token
      console.log("=> Access token is not valid sending refresh token... ");


      if(inverse) this.router.navigate([invalidDest]);

    }
    else{
      // access token is valid so we can continue operation
      if(!inverse) this.router.navigate([invalidDest]);

    }

  },error => {
    console.log("Error while validating token");

  },
  () => {
    // 'onCompleted' callback.
    // No errors, route to new page here

  }
);
 }
```

Anyway you can do something like that to prevent the page render before the subscription has finished:

Component example:

```
private canRender = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.service.login(...)
   .subscribe( data => {
      //do Stuff
      this.canRender = true;
   });
}
```

related html to component :

```
<div ngIf="canRender">
   Content here will be render when you have the data you needed
   <!-- that when the line "this.canRender = true;" will be executed
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my issue. But can you explain that if it is bad to put logic in service or it's just a trend..

Comment: As far as I've learned it's a bad practise because, usually, services are shared by various component, and if you put some logic it could happen that, in certain situation, this logic is not needed for some components. Also once a wise man told me "It's MVC pattern, components do logic, services just http call and Guard stuff"

Comment: @JacopoSciampi  According to Plurlsight: "A reusable Angular service is designed to encapsulate business logic and data with different components of Angular."  I have also always been under the impression that services are almost for logic *because* they are shared between components. Reduces duplicate code that way.  Source: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/understanding-the-purpose-of-services-in-angular